# Execution context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object named Gallery with several properties and methods. 
One of them, setCurrentPicture, removes all existing photos and videos DOM elements from gallery container before showing new photo/video. Besides my gallery stops playing video (set this to pause mode) when the user clicks on it. This is togglePlayVideo method inside the Gallery prototype. First I remove elements from DOM and then showing new content. If this is video, I add eventListener to document, 
use bind method.

So, in the setCurrentPicture I want to remove EventListener on video elements. Is it possible to bind this context to document inside Array.prototype.forEach method when deleting eventListener? If I saved the necessary context into new variable then I got succeed. But then I'm trying bind, my IDE is saying 'Potentially invalid usage of this'.

Code snippet:

```
Gallery.prototype = {
  setCurrentPicture: function(currentPhoto) {
        var self = this;

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.children, function(item) {
          if (item.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
            document.removeEventListener('click', self.togglePlayVideo);
          }
          if (item.tagName === 'VIDEO' || item.tagName === 'IMG') {
            container.removeChild(item);
          }
        });

       if (pictures[currentPhoto] instanceof Video) {
          var video = document.createElement('video');
          ....
          document.addEventListener('click', self.togglePlayVideo);
        }
    },
},

 togglePlayVideo: function(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
        return e.target.paused ? e.target.play() : e.target.pause();
      }
    }
}
```

In case of addition `document.addEventListener('click', self.togglePlayVideo);`
I can use bind instead of `self: document.addEventListener('click', this.togglePlayVideo.bind(this)`.

Can I use bind in removeEventListener?
 document.removeEventListener('click', this.togglePlayVideo.bind(this);

Comment: What is your question? (And can you please format your code properly)

Comment: when you write something like var self = this; u are using lexacal scope. if you want to set "this" to a particular value when you call your function you can use "function_name.apply(what_supposed_to_be_this, function_arguments)". And you obviously don't need to use self = this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best for you is to get familiar with what is "this" and what is "bind". You can do this by reading this [brilliant description](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md)

and [second part](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)

To cut a long story short - when you declare a function with "this" like this:

1. in defaul case "this" will be the Window object

   `var f = function(){return this;};`

   `f(); //will return Window object`
2. when an object owns a link to your function like this:

   `var f = function(){return this;};`

   `var o = {func: f};`

   `o.func(); // will return the "o" object becuase "this" becomes o object`
3. when you use explicit binding like call/apply you'll set this to a particular value like this:

   `var f = function(){return this;};`

   `var obj = {};`

   `f.call(obj); // will return your obj`
4. and there is so called "hard binding". used like this:

   `var f = function(){return this;};`

   `var obj1 = {num:1};`

   `var obj2 = {num:2};`

   `var boundFunc = f.bind(obj1); //now it's hardbound to obj1`

   `//let's try to switch this by using "call"`

   `boundFunc.call(obj2); // will return obj1, because it's hardbound`
5. and this can be affected when function is called with "new" keyword:

   `f = function(){ this.a =1; this.b =2; };`

   `var obj = new f(); // will set brand new object as "this" and return it`

   `//so we will get {a:1, b:2} object as a result`

Comment: thanks for the answer, the problem is that I'm using method of object inside other method of those object, and inside forEach loop I have this = undefined.

Comment: if you refer to case #4 (hardbinding) you'll see that "bind" returns a new function which is bound to a value you passed to "bind" and that bound function won't ever loose it's this. hope this helps

Comment: I'm also have tried to use static method:
document.removeEventListener('click', Gallery.togglePlayVideo);
But not sure that in this case event listener would be removed from particular gallery from which it has been added to document

Comment: I have this in constructor:
 this.togglePlayVideo = this.togglePlayVideo.bind(this);

Comment: You shold have a link to your callback function (var cb = function(){your_callback_code}), then you should find an element with var elem = document.getElementById('my-input') (or document.getElementsByClassName) and then to remove the listener you call elem.removeEventListener('click', callback)

Answer (score 0):

I should add bind this to Array.prototype.forEach.call instead of implementing this to callback function.

```
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.children, function(item) {
          if (item.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.togglePlayVideo);
          }
          if (item.tagName === 'VIDEO' || item.tagName === 'IMG') {
            container.removeChild(item);
          }
        }.bind(this));
```

Thanks to all for the answers.